# Drop Down List Across Views/Models

Tags: drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a dropdown list, which is simple enough if the list is in the same view as the model/controller, however I am trying to create the dropdown list in another view. I am including the "using.samplemodel.Models;" using statement which seems to work as far as being able to access the right database, however no matter which method I use to call the list items in the Database (which is already populate) I keep getting the error "there is no key "Categories" or even i use the Id field in the statement, I am currently using the Viewbag option to call the database information, however, no matter which method I try, I still get the same error.

```
 The class of the view I am wanting to use drop down list in:

namespace Fake.Models
{
    public class Fake
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<SelectList> Categories { get; set; }

      }
}



 Model of the Category class pulling from database:

namespace Fake.Models
{
    public class Categories
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
}




 controller of the view intended to use dropdown list:

namespace Fake.Controllers
{
    public class FakeController : Controller
    {

        FakeDb _db = new FakeDb();


        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = from a in _db.Fake1 orderby a.Date ascending select a;
            ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(_db.Categories, "Id", "CategoryName");
            return View(model);
        }




The view I am trying to get dropdown list to work in:

@model fakename.Models.Modelname
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-group col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Categories", "Select Category")
            // Omitted Info not related
        </div>
}
```

Sorry the Snippets here dont exatly match up as I intended with this form. So I am including a window snip of the code as jpeg here [Code in Notepad Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvbrk.jpg) Just in case.

Comment: I know the database is working because in the category views I am able to update the categories database with edit,delete,create etc. so the problem is not with the database or the categories class (i think) the problem seems to be with trying to transfer the information from the categories to the "fake" view to a drop down list

Comment: I am only using one database, I have multiple tables in the one database, which I created all my views for this application, each one works as intended respectively.

Comment: Ok, I solved that problem, I was actually placing the viewbag code in the wrong area in the controller, however NOW I am gettinga "There is no ViewData Item of Type 'Ienumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key "Categories",     Even if I type "Id" which is what is on my table for Categories, then still get the same error, What do I need to put in this @Html.Dropdownlist(etc, etc etc) to get it to work, If I comment out just this line, the page will open, the problem is with the dropdownlist html helper or the viewbag code in controller, or the "fake" class of the page I want it to load in.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer was simple. But still complicated to a newbie like me...needed ado.net entity  for it to work.